# .NET RegEx help

Tags: c#, regex

I am very inexperienced when it comes to regular expressions. What I'm trying to do is iterate through a list of strings and try to locate strings that are of a certain pattern. The strings I am interested in will be in the form of `"some text ***{some text}***"`
How do I write a RegEx to match up to? I was trying this:

```
Regex expression = new Regex("***");
```

but this gives me an error. `parsing "***" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.`

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I'm trying to loop through select list options and add a css class to the options that are relevant.

```
Regex expression = new Regex("***");
foreach (ListItem li in listItemCollection)
{
    if (expression.IsMatch(li.Value))
        li.Attributes.Add("class", "highlight1");
}
```

but this obviously isn't working.

Any help is appreciated,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 9):

You need to escape the asterisk, as it's a valid metacharacter in RegExp.

```
Regex expression = new Regex(@"\*\*\*");
```

Comment: Regex.Escape is also useful:

new Regex(Regex.Escape("***"));

Answer (score 3):

* has a special meaning in regular expression.

If you are looking to match 3 asteriks, try

```
Regex expression = new Regex(@"\*\*\*");
```

**EDIT:**

If you are only trying to verify if a string contains "***", look at [bdukes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161510/net-regex-help/1161586#1161586).

Answer (score 3):

If all you're trying to do is match three asterisks, why not just use the [string.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method instead of a regular expression?

```
foreach (ListItem li in listItemCollection)
{
    if (li.Value.Contains("***"))
        li.Attributes.Add("class", "highlight1");
}
```

Comment: +1 for thinking about the actual problem instead of just fixing the code. This is a better idea instead of using Regex.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
\*\*\*[^\*]+\*\*\*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to test out regexes, get an application for testing. [Any of these](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=.net%2Bregex%2Btester) would be a good start. I've been attached to [Chris Sells's tester](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/#regexd) for a long time but there are lots out there.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this regex pattern

```
\*{3}\{[^\}]*}\*{3}
```

This will find `***{some text}***`

If you want the text before the * you should use this one

```
^[\w\s]*\*{3}\{[^\}]*\}\*{3}
```

- `^` - beginning of the input
- `[\w\s]*` any char in a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ and white space, 0 or more times
- `\*{3}` three asterisks
- `\{` match `{`
- `[^\}]*` any char except `}` 0 or more times
- `\}` match `}`
- `\*{3}` match three asterisks

Comment: @Cédric, notice the correction re: `\w` - it matches digits, too. Also, in some regex flavors `\w` matches letters and digits from all writing systems, not just the ASCII ones.